# Date format Mail Merge Word Excel

Tags: excel, ms-word, mailmerge

I'm using the *Dutch version* of Word and Excel 2016 to fill in data from an Excel table in a Word document using Mail Merge. When doing so, my dates are represented as a number. I tried using the \@ format, both in English as in Dutch, but nothing is working. I checked the Excel file and the data is properly formatted as a date. So far, I tried the following formats in my Word document, including adding and removing spaces before and after the quotation marks:

- {MERGEFIELD FieldName \@ "dd-mm-jjjj"}
- {MERGEFIELD FieldName \@ "dd-MM-yyyy"}
- {MERGEFIELD FieldName .\@ "dd-MM-yyyy"} (adding the dot was only mentioned on one website)

I import the data using the 'Use an Existing List' and 'Insert Merge Fields' function in Word.

Does anyone know what I should change to get a proper Date format in my Word document?

FYI, other numbering formats are working fine.

Comment: How is the data transferred from Excel -> Word?

Comment: I import the data using the 'Use an Existing List' and 'Insert Merge Fields' function in Word.

Answer (score 0):

If the dates are being represented as numbers, that means you have mixed data types in the Excel column.

By default, Word 2002 & later use the OLE DB provider to get records from the data source. Because the OLE DB provider is designed to return data in a way that is compatible with databases, it requires a specific data type for each field, and every record in that field must be of that data type. When using other data sources, the OLE DB provider queries the first 8 records to determine the data type for each field (the 8 can be changed in the Windows Registry, but it’s not advisable to do so). This can lead to unexpected results with data sources such as Excel workbooks, where rows (records) in a column (field) can have different data types.

When the OLE DB provider gets data from a column with mixed data types, records that don’t conform to the determined data type for the column are liable to not be handled correctly. The most common common mailmerge issue arising out of this include:

- numbers but not text or dates being output; and
- dates being output as numbers,

for some records.

Ideally, one would ensure each field has only one data type. Workarounds include:

- Inserting a dummy first record containing data in the format that
  is not being output correctly; or
- Reordering the data so the first
  record has content in the format that is not otherwise being output
  correctly.

If you're unable to do either, see *Importing Date and Time Values From Excel and Access* in my **Microsoft Word Date Calculation Tutorial**, avialble at:

- http://www.msofficeforums.com/word/38719-microsoft-word-date-calculation-tutorial.html

or:

- http://www.gmayor.com/downloads.htm#Third_party

Do read the document's introductory material.